import sqlite3 creating table python
I cannot create a table in SQLite in Python with the following code. Can you help me where is the error in the code?
conn = sqlite3.connect('hospital.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute(""""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hastalar(
        isim    TEXT NOT NULL,
        soyad   TEXT NOT NULL,
        HastaID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        dgtarih TEXT NOT NULL,
        cinsiyet    TEXT NOT NULL,
        telefon TEXT NOT NULL,
        adres   TEXT,
        RandevuID   INTEGER,
        RaporID INTEGER
    ) """)

conn.commit()
conn.close()

This is the error I get
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProLab7\app.py", line 10, in 
c.execute(""""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hastalar(
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hastalar(
isim    TEXT NOT NULL,
soyad   TEXT NOT NULL,
HastaID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
dgtarih TEXT NOT NULL,
cinsiyet        TEXT NOT NULL,
telefon TEXT NOT NULL,
adres   TEXT,
RandevuID       INTEGER,
RaporID INTEGER
) "

You have an extra quote at the beginning of your statement.
